# RNA degradation plot: why curves are so smooth?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm analysing data from Affymetrix microarrays. I don't understand why I get such smooth curves in the RNA degradation plots.
This is what I get:
[image]
I would expect sharp curves like these:
[image]
Is there something wrong with the script I used?

```
degradation <- AffyRNAdeg(Data)
plotAffyRNAdeg(degradation, transform = "shift.scale", cols = NULL)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Consider asking questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Answer (score 0):

The most important point in degradation plots is the slope of each cure. In your plot they are good. I think don't be worry about smoothness and see the links ([link1](http://www.slideshare.net/ueb52/analysis-uebuat-bioinformatics-course-session-23-vhir-barcelona), [link2](http://arrayanalysis.org/main.html) and [link3](https://genevestigator.com/userdocs/manual/qc.html)) which have similar results.